# Installation DVD not showing up as an additional software repository

Tags: linux-mint

I recently installed Mint 17 on my Macbook Pro. I have zero internet access as the wifi is not working at all and the wired ethernet is refusing to connect. I've looked and I think I found a solution but I need to be able to install ethtool. I'm hoping this is on the installation cd to install but I can't get the DVD to show up under additional sources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to rip the DVD into an .iso image and then mount and add it under additional sources.

Steps:

```
sudo mkdir /aptoncd-mountpoint
sudo mount /media/USB/aptoncd.iso ~/aptoncd-mountpoint -oloop
sudo apt-cdrom -d=/aptoncd-mountpoint add
```

Found here for Ubuntu, but should also work for Mint:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/4694/how-to-use-a-iso-image-as-a-cd-rom-repository